# How to get sum of ultrawingridcolumn into textbox below

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview, infragistics

I have a requirement where I want to sum TotalCost in below grid and show the sum result in Total Textbox below.

I am using infragistics ultrawingrid here. How can I do that

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply loop over the rows collection and for each row convert the value of the specific column to a decimal adding it to a running total. At the end set the text property of the TextBox to the conversion in string of the running total using the predefined currency format specifier

```
decimal total = 0m;
foreach(UltraGridRow row in grid.Rows)
{
    total += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["TotalCost"].Value);
}
textBox1.Text = total.ToString("C");
```

Keep in mind that the UltraGrid has a Summaries collection property that you can use to show the total of any column directly under the referenced column in a special "Summary" area.

```
SummarySettings ss = null;
ss = grid.Bands[0].Summaries.Add("mySum", 
         SummaryType.Sum, null, 
         grid.Bands[0].Columns["TotalCost"], 
         SummaryPosition.UseSummaryPositionColumn, 
         grid.Bands[0].Columns["TotalCost"]);
ss.DisplayFormat = "{0:C}";
ss.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Red;
ss.Appearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Right;
grid.DisplayLayout.Override.SummaryDisplayArea = SummaryDisplayAreas.BottomFixed;
```